# Can I use a foot pedal to send mouse clicks and/or modifier keys ergonomically?

Tags: computers, ankle, ergonomics, repetitive-strain-injury

When using computers, I often want to send more inputs than my keyboard can. I once tried to use a foot pedal (a.k.a. footswitch) to send mouse clicks and modifier keys, but it seemed to put a lot of strain on my ankle. Is it possible to use a foot pedal to send mouse clicks and modifier keys without getting any [RSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury)-like issues, and if so, how shall I use it ergonomically?

---

Here is the foot pedal I use: [Savant Elite Dual Action USB Foot Switch by Kinesis Corporation](http://www.spectronicsinoz.com/product/savant-elite-dual-action-usb-foot-switch)

[image]

My posture:

[image]

Comment: <comments deleted> Please don't answer in comments

Answer (score 8):

RSI refers to Repetitive Stress Injury. You see the word 'repetitive' there? So, it has to come with **anything** that you repeatedly do. No matter wrist, ankle, elbow, knee!

But then, if you think a bit more, the strength we have in our extremities is different from each other. Said that, by nature, legs are stronger than hands. Extending this further, toes are stronger than fingers, knee ...than elbow, and hip joint ...than shoulder. The same goes true in case of foreleg vs forearm, thighs vs biceps and so ankle vs wrist.

I don't say that using ankles won't cause RSI), BUT as compared to wrists, your ankles are a bit stronger so they'll take *longer* time to get affected. But RSI -repetitive...so doing it again and again won't spare you at all!

Comment: Thanks! 1) Yes sure any repetitive movements is RSI-prone but ergonomics is here to mitigate the risk: I'm looking for ergonomics advice on how to reduce the risk of RSI, and to what extent it is RSI-prone 2) Have you tried to use a foot switch to send mouse clicks all day long? My feeling was that it puts more strain on ankles than the mouse puts on hands/wrists.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to position the pedal the way we have accelerator in a car. But that's pure logical advice! :)